Search within a Multiple Range of numbers in a cell in Excel?
I have 2 columns on my worksheet, one of names and other is supposed to be ranges of numbers like this

Formula will go in the result cell and it will take input form the Search Cell.
I want to search a specific number in the search cell and get the assigned name to that number in the result cell basically
I tried different formulas, but unable to put all together to get the desired result


Formula in G2:
=FILTER(B1:B3,MAP(C1:C3,LAMBDA(x,LET(y,TEXTSPLIT(x,", "),OR((--TEXTBEFORE(y,"-",,,,y)<=F2)*(--TEXTAFTER(y,"-",,,,y)>=F2))))))


Beautiful! LET(y,TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(x,",")) to make it a bit tolerant?

@nkalvi, I appreciate your comment (and the coffee you have bought me, awesome!). And since you are a supporter now, if you have some ideas I can post about on my buymeacoffee just let me know ;)

Here is another way to accomplish the desired output, although this doesn't needs a LAMBDA() helper function. And uses TEXTSPLIT() + TEXTAFTER() + TOCOL() and OfCourse the XLOOKUP() .


• Formula used in cell F2
=LET(
     α, C1:C3,
     δ, --TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(","&α,",",{1,2,3}),"-",,1),
     φ, --TEXTAFTER(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(", "&C1:C3,", ",{1,2,3}),","),"-",,,,TAKE(δ,,-1)),
     XLOOKUP(1,(E2>=TOCOL(δ,2))*(E2<=TOCOL(φ,2)),TOCOL(IF((δ<>"")*(φ<>""),B1:B3),2),""))


CAVEAT: Only one thing to note which is quite important, and should be informed that {1,2,3} this represent the max number of delimiters that is for the commas, if you want to make dynamic it is quite possible, but if an eyeroll is enough to count the number of delimiters then just increase/decrease it as per suit. like if there are max 4, then SEQUENCE(,4) or {1,2,3,4} or 5/6 etc whatever it may have. 

